# About $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, with $A_n=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:-e^{-x^2/n}<y\le e^{-x^2/n}\}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am asking this question as I would like to improve my understanding about a couple of things.

Since $e^{-x^2/n}$ converges monotonically to $1$, I think we have $$A=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:x\ne0, y\in\left(-1,-e^{-x^2}\right)\cup\left[e^{-x^2},1\right)\right\}\cup\{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:-y\in(-1,1]\}.$$Among the points of this set, is it true that $\{(x,e^{-x^2})\in\mathbb{R^2}:x\in\mathbb{R\backslash\{0\}}\}\cup\{(0,1)\}=\{(x,e^{-x^2})\in\mathbb{R^2}:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is the set of all the boundary points? Furthermore, does the density of $\mathbb{R}$ indeed imply $A'=A$?

Comment: was my answer helpful? Can you determine the boundary of $A$ now?

Comment: @ForeverMozart: Yes, it was. I commented and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should get $A=[\mathbb R \times (-1,1) ]\cup \{(0,1)\}$.

$f(x)=\pm e^{-x^2}$:

[image: here]

Dividing by $n$ stretches the graph horizontally by a factor of $\sqrt n$.

$f(x)=\pm e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$:

[image]

$f(x)=\pm e^{\frac{-x^2}{1000}}$:

[image]

$A_n$ is the set of all points "enclosed" by the graph of $f(x)=\pm e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}$.

Clearly each $$A_n\subseteq [\mathbb R \times (-1,1)]\cup \{(0,1)\}.$$

For the other inclusion, just note that for any $(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times  [0,1)$  there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $e^{\frac{-x^2}{n}}>y$, and similarly for $(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times (-1,0]$.

Now you can easily determine the set of boundary points.

Comment: Thank you, graphing the functions was very useful. I do see now why I was wrong about the form of $A$. Is the boundary $\{(x,\pm1)\in\mathbb{R^2}\}$? Is $A'=A\cup\{(x,\pm1)\in\mathbb{R^2}\}$?

Comment: Yes that is correct.